# Do graphs form groups under addition?

Tags: graph-theory

I just started studying graph theory, but according to the existence of the null graph and the definition of graph addition, they seem (non-directional graphs) to form a group.

Is this true?

Comment: What would you propose to be the inverse of graph addition?  What two nonempty graphs can be added to get the empty graph?

Comment: What would be the inverse of a graph?

Comment: You may be looking for the concept of a [monoidal category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_category).

Answer (score -1):

Community wiki answer so the question can be closed:

As explained in the comments, graphs do not form a group under (this) addition.

Comment: The comments so far have been questions (i.e., What would be the inverse of a graph?), but questions by themselves certainly don't prove anything, and it's not obvious, to me at least, that an identity, inverses, etc can't be defined. So at this point I don't believe the question was answered.